# Angular NgFor with keyvalue pipe displays out of order

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, ngfor

I'm trying to make a hexgrid. So I retrieve a collection of hexes from firestore, sort them by id, move them to a row of 10 (so the first 10 go into 'row0', the next 10 into 'row1', etc), and use ngFor to display them.

The problem is when I display them I get this:

row0

row1

row10

row11

row2

row3

row4

row5

row6

row7

row8

row9

so I'm obviously missing something. I would think that they are out of order but I am console.logging the rows and seeing them in order as expected:

> Rows [row0: Array(10), row1: Array(10), row2: Array(10), row3: Array(10), row4: Array(10), …] object

I can see that the order seems to be based off the first number after 'row' but am not sure why.

TS:

Service

```
export class FirestoreService {

  constructor(private db:AngularFirestore) { }

  getHexes(){
    let hexRows = []

    let hexes = this.db.collection('hexes', ref=> ref.orderBy('id')).valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
      data.forEach((hex, index) => {
        let rowNum = Math.floor(index / 10)

        if(hexRows[`row${rowNum}`] == undefined){
          hexRows[`row${rowNum}`] = []
        }
        hexRows[`row${rowNum}`].push(hex)
      })
      console.log('Rows', hexRows, typeof hexRows);
    })

    return hexRows
  }
```

Component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.hexRows = this.afs.getHexes()
  }
```

HTML:

Component

```
<div *ngFor="let row of hexRows | keyvalue">
  {{row.key}}
</div>
```

***Update***

So following Deborah's lead I tried using a comparefn and "fixed it" accidentally. I made a quick test function named 'orderByRowNum' and when I checked to see if it ran it looks like it ordered the list as expected:

TS:

```
orderByRowNum = (a,b) => {
    console.log('A', a);
    return a
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of hexRows | keyvalue:orderByRowNum">
  {{row.key}}
</div>
```

This is probably a horrible implementation and I'm not 100% sure why it works but I'm going to post it because it at least seems like progress.

Comment: looks like they're ordered alphabetically, not numerically, i.e. "0", "1", "10", "11"...

Comment: So when I console.log it is it just ordering it for me somehow?

Comment: The `keyvalue` pipe is ordering them. From the docs: `The output array will be ordered by keys. By default the comparator will be by Unicode point value. You can optionally pass a compareFn if your keys are complex types.` (https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clearing that up. If you want to post that as an answer I'd gladly accept it!

Comment: @gv0000, your comparator is wrong, must be like (a,b)=> { return (+a.substring(3))>(+b.substring(3))}

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it seems that localeCompare would help, but for me it didn't help, so I wouldn't rely simply on it.

You need to apply natural sort algorithm to sort keys.

Try this. Algorithm of natural sort in javascript I took from here https://snipplr.com/view/36012/javascript-natural-sort/ and refactored it to fit typescript rules better. Also localeCompare is applied instead of native string compactor.

```
private orderByRowNum = (aKv: KeyValue<string, any>, bKv: KeyValue<string, any>) => {

    const rx: RegExp = /(\d+)|(\D+)/g;
    const rd: RegExp = /\d+/;

    const as: string = aKv.key;
    const bs: string = bKv.key;

    const a: RegExpMatchArray = String(as).match(rx);
    const b: RegExpMatchArray = String(bs).match(rx);

    while (a.length && b.length) {
        const a1: string = a.shift();
        const b1: string = b.shift();
        if (rd.test(a1) || rd.test(b1)){
            if (!rd.test(a1)) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (!rd.test(b1)) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (a1 !== b1) {
                return Number(a1) - Number(b1);
            }
        } else {
            if (a1 !== b1) {
                return a1.localeCompare(b1);
            }
        }
    }
    return a.length - b.length;
}
```

It is better to take it out to some util class to make it more reusable.